# How to delete certain folders (with 4words or more) and all its files via SSH?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

This just delete one folder and all files in it: rm -rf /path/folder/

But I have thousands folders: And I want to delete all folders that has 4 or more words in it.

/path/folder/new-folder-1 
/path/folder/another-folder-2 
/path/folder/old-folder-very-old-1   ===delete this 
/path/folder/another-folder-very-old-1 ===delete this 
/path/folder/just-another-new-junk-folder ===delete this 
/path/folder/twin-folder-1

Comment: Would you also want to delete `another-old-folder-4`?

Comment: @NateEldredge yes

Answer (score 2):

You may try `ls -al /path/folder/?*-?*-?*-?*` (simple listing, no delete).

If the desired folders are correctly listed, and **only those**, then you can go ahead with the `rm -rf /path/folder/?*-?*-?*-?*`.

For more precaution, you may move the selected directories to a dedicated temporary folder and check that all is OK, before deleting this dedicated temporary folder.

You are the only responsible of the delete command :-)

Best regards

Comment: I know. thanks. i will try with dummy folders first.